# Continuous Delivery on GCP Compute Engine

Tags: docker, gitlab, google-compute-engine

I have a pipeline on GitLab where on every push, a build is triggered and if all tests pass on master branch, a Docker image is build an published to GitLab Registry.

On Google Cloud Platform I have a Compute Engine ( VM ) instance with a docker image installed on it ( on GCP I have also a docker image published in Google Container Registry - I did it manually for now ).

I want to automatize step of updating Docker image on GCP Computer Engine instance.

1. How I should access GitLab regitry from GCP even if I will remove Compute Engine instances and I will create others ?
2. How to update a docker image that is running inside Compute Engine without restarting VM and without connecting to SSH ? ( I would like to have posibility to trigger and update from GitLab when a Docker image is published to registry ).

Note: I'm not ready at this moment to use Kubernetes for my project.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe this link will help you https://medium.com/evenbit/an-easy-guide-to-automatically-deploy-your-google-app-engine-project-with-gitlab-ci-48cb84757125

Comment: thank you for this article, I'm using Compute Engine and Docker and I got some ideas about how to install google-cloud-sdk on gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the scripts/commands (that requires to access GitLab images) as a file in the Google Cloud [bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets). Make that file as executable and run it through the respective VMs as a workaround. Make sure that you have given respective [access control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/bucketAccessControls) over the bucket as well.

You can also check this [administration](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/) articles on GitLab container Registry for build and push [images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/container_registry.html#build-and-push-images). As per [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/container_registry.html#control-container-registry-from-within-gitlab) document GitLab also offers container registry management panel which helps to manage the images within their project.

You can also make use of the script/command for updating the docker images under a executable file and run it with the help of crontab, which may ultimately update the docker images in the VM. You would need to include the commands required to trigger the update to GitLab as well.

Integration of gitlab with GCP platform is not available right now. However, there is an ongoing [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/67051803) for connecting GitLab repository with Google Container builder. You can check the FR and add comments if you wish.